# Get URL from BeautifulSoup object

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Somebody is handing my function a BeautifulSoup object (BS4) that he has gotten using the typical call:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(url)
```

my code:

```
def doSomethingUseful(soup):
    url = soup.???
```

How do I get the original URL from the soup object? I tried reading the docs AND the BeautifulSoup source code... I'm still not sure.

Comment: I'm not sure what your project entails, but you could look into selenium at https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/ 
Selenium allows you to call `driver.current_url` which might solve your problem. As well you can run it in headless and many of the methods for finding elements on the page are basically the same as BeautifulSoup

Comment: beautiful soup doesn't get a URL , it gets a html and parse it.

Comment: @ᴀʀᴍᴀɴ if you post that I'll accept it

Comment: @QED actually it is not an answer it is just a hint that shows you the way , I think it is better to be left as a comment.

Comment: It led to the answer for me, but ok. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the `url` variable is a string of an actual URL, then you should just forget the BeautifulSoup here and use the same variable `url`.  You should be using BeautifulSoup to parse HTML code, not a simple URL.  In fact, if you try to use it like this, you get a warning:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> url = "https://foo"
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(url)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py:336: UserWarning: "https://foo" looks like a URL. Beautiful Soup is not an HTTP client. You should probably use an HTTP client like requests to get the document behind the URL, and feed that document to Beautiful Soup.
  ' that document to Beautiful Soup.' % decoded_markup
```

Since the URL is just a string, BeautifulSoup doesn't really know what to do with it when you "soupify" it, except for wrapping it up in basic HTML:

```
>>> soup
<html><body><p>https://foo</p></body></html>
```

If you still wanted to extract the URL from this, you could just use `.text` on the object, since it's the only thing in there:

```
>>> print(soup.text)
https://foo
```

If on the other hand `url` is **not** really a URL at all but rather a bunch of HTML code (in which case the variable name would be very misleading), then how you'd extract a specific link inside would beg the question of how it's in your code. Doing a `find` to get the first `a` tag, then extracting the `href` value would be one way.

```
>>> actual_html = '<html><body><a href="http://moo">My link text</a></body></html>'
>>> newsoup = BeautifulSoup(actual_html)
>>> newsoup.find('a')['href']
'http://moo'
```

Comment: Oops! You are right and I should have known better. No problem, I'll just pass the original URL into my function. I'll accept your answer in a few minutes when SO allows it.

Comment: What about if I have a bunch of `html`s saved on disk and now want to retrieve the original url which was used to get the html? Is something like this possible?

Comment: @theProcrastinator : If you just have a bunch of .html files sitting on a disk, there's no real way of knowing where they were downloaded from, unless maybe the HTML code itself has some URLs inside that might indicate that (e.g., absolute links to other pages on the same site).  Otherwise it's like trying to figure out where a .jpg was downloaded from, just by looking at the picture.

Comment: Actually, I found all the urls. They were in the `meta` tag. So, a simple `soup.find_all("meta")` did the trick. And I also found out that the url (if present) is mostly in the `meta` tag only. Thanks though for the time :)